# How do I set up a Custom View in Server Manager for a particular IIS Site ID?

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging, event-viewer

I'm looking to set up a custom view for a particular site on our IIS, in this case, ID 28.  I can get as far as creating

Last 30 days, critical, error and warning by log (application) with the keyword 'Classic' which will pick up all our .Net appliction errors.  There is no evidence in the log to state what IIS site ID it originated from though.

How can I amend the filter to target at least either:
Request Information > Thread Account Name (which is the IIS pool name as far as I can see)
or
Application Information > Application Path.

Could somebody point me in the right direction to amend the query XML manually to target either of the above?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS debug diagnostic tool available from Microsoft allows you to track particular application pools and processes.  It's available from:

www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26798

Instructions for particular types of log tracking is available from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx

Note that these instructions are for 1.1 rather than 1.2 but are still relevant.